# .htaccess redirect directory to php script including params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

Hi I have read all related posts I could find on stackoverflow. Some came close and others were just not applicable or just didn't seem to work for me.

I have an external party calling my ip xxx.xxx.xx.xx:port/hello/world?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3

What I want is to forward this request to a php script that will process these requests.

I however cannot change the call the third party make. With that in mind I thought about implementing something with .htaccess. I would make a script called world.php. I would than remove the extention calling of php by placing this in my .htaccess file. This would be hack to make that path execute my script with those params.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It didn't work.

So i thought I could try redirect but those don't seem to keep the params. 
Tried redirecting everything that went to the path hello/ to my script it didn't seem to work either

Any help I will be most great full.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in `/hello/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hello/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

You will then get your `/hello/word.php` invoked with all the parameters in the request.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it, but can you explain what it is doing? Or direct me a good tutorial on the commands of .htaccess.

Comment: http://askapache.com is good site for .htaccess stuff. This rule is checking whether a `.php` exists by using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f` condition and making sure it is not a directory using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any problems with this rule.